# How to convert an astroid node to an AST one in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, python-3.7

So, the question is in the title.

If it does not make sense to do such a thing, is it possible to visit a tree
like in `AST` with `ast.NodeVisitor` (with `generic_visit` and `visit_XXXX` methods).

I know that we can write the `visit_XXXX` and `leave_XXXX` methods with  `astroid`
but the prorgam I am writting (a pylint plugin) checks a loop (e.g a while loop) and
to avoid some methods to occur outside the while loop, I wrote another class that implements the `visit_XXXX` functions for nodes I am interested in in the while loop body.

I do not find a way to do this with `astroid` whereas with `AST` I can write a class that inherits `ast.NodeVisitor` and look for what I want.

Can anybody help ?

Thank You